How to get AABB of MeshInstance3D deformed by bones of a Skeleton3D?
I have a MeshInstance3D which can be deformed via the bones in a Skeleton3D by changing their position, rotation, etc as such:

How do I get the bounding box / AABB of the deformed mesh?
As you can clearly see the bounding box (orange) retrieved by get_aabb() is only of the mesh in rest post

Since there was no inbuilt method, I wrote my own:
func get_precise_aabb(mesh_instance : MeshInstance3D):
    
    var skeleton:Skeleton3D = mesh_instance.get_node_or_null(mesh_instance.skeleton)
    var low : Vector3 = Vector3.INF
    var high : Vector3 = -Vector3.INF
    
    for surface in mesh_instance.mesh.get_surface_count():
        var data := mesh_instance.mesh.surface_get_arrays(surface)
        var vertices:Array = data[Mesh.ARRAY_VERTEX]
        var vert_map := {} # to avoid recalculating
        
        for vert_idx in len(vertices):
            var vert = vertices[vert_idx]
            
            if(vert in vert_map):
                continue
            else:
                vert_map[vert]=null
            
            if(skeleton and mesh_instance.skin):
                var bones:Array = data[Mesh.ARRAY_BONES]
                var weights:Array = data[Mesh.ARRAY_WEIGHTS]
                var bone_count := len(weights)/len(vertices)
                var transformed_vert = Vector3.ZERO
                for i in bone_count:
                    var weight = weights[vert_idx * bone_count + i]
                    
                    if(!weight):
                        continue
                    
                    var bone_idx = bones[vert_idx * bone_count + i]
                    var bind_pose = mesh_instance.skin.get_bind_pose(bone_idx)
                    var bone_global_pose = skeleton.get_bone_global_pose(bone_idx)
                    transformed_vert += (bone_global_pose * bind_pose * vert) * weight
                
                vert = transformed_vert
            
            vert=mesh_instance.global_transform * vert
            
            low.x = vert.x if low.x > vert.x else low.x
            high.x = vert.x if vert.x > high.x else high.x
            
            low.y = vert.y if low.y > vert.y else low.y
            high.y = vert.y if vert.y > high.y else high.y
            
            low.z = vert.z if low.z > vert.z else low.z
            high.z = vert.z if vert.z > high.z else high.z
    
    return AABB(low, high - low)

Hope this helps :)
